# Remove the app badge at a given hour

Tags: iphone, notifications

My app uses badge to count the number of smoked cigarettes in the current day. I would like the app to remove the badge at the midnight, when a new day begins... Is it possible to do that?

I mean, doing that while the app is closed!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  I don't think there is an elegant way to handle this; even multi-tasking falls short of being able to wake the app to perform a task.  The only thing you're allowed to do is schedule a Local Notification, but this is only allowed to increase the badge number - sending a badge number of "0" indicates "no change".

Sorry there isn't a better answer.

andrew

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just check, on application startup, if it was already started that day, and if not, remove the badge?

Comment: This is what i'm doing right now, but it's not so elegant: 'till you open the app the badge of the previous day still remain visible!